# iPhone App with Clips Rules Engine

Tags: iphone, objective-c, artificial-intelligence, rule-engine, clips

I am developing an iPhone app that uses [CLIPS RULES ENGINE](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/).
I have integrated it successfully with XCode using below code.

```
InitializeEnvironment();
Clear(); 

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"animal" ofType:@"clp"];

NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; 

if (myData) {

    char *clipsFileChar = (char *)[filePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 

    IncrementGCLocks();
    Load(clipsFileChar);
    Reset();
    AssertString("(find-all-facts ((?f state-list)) FALSE)"); 

    int numberRulesFired = Run(-1); 
    NSLog(@"Number of rules that fired: %d", numberRulesFired); 

    DecrementGCLocks(); 
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Could not find file %@", filePath);
}
```

the problem is when I run my app, it goes to infinite loop from line `int numberRulesFired = Run(-1);`.
Please help me if you have any idea.......
Thanks.. :)

Comment: i have solved this problem, code is on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723202/how-to-get-response-from-clpclips-file/11771089#11771089 hope it helps...